# Error C3867: function call missing argument list

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, function-pointers, function-call

I'm trying to compile a code in Visual Studio, but I keep getting the following error:

> Error  4   error C3867: 'MindSet::Form1::handleDataValueFunc': function call missing argument list; use '&MindSet::Form1::handleDataValueFunc' to create a pointer to member   c:\documents and settings\licap\desktop\mindset\mindset\mindset\Form1.h 122 1   MindSet

This is my code

```
#pragma endregion
void handleDataValueFunc(unsigned char extendedCodeLevel, unsigned char code,
    unsigned char valueLength, const unsigned char *value, void *customData)
{
    FILE *arq1;
    FILE *arq2;
    FILE *arq3;
        arq1 = fopen("raw.txt","a");
        arq2 = fopen("atencao.txt","a");
        arq3 = fopen("meditacao.txt","a");

    if (extendedCodeLevel == 0 && code == RAW_WAVE_CODE)
    {
        short rawValue = ((value[0] << 8) & 0xff00) | (0x00ff & value[1]);
        printf("%d\n", rawValue);
        fprintf(arq1,"%d\n",rawValue);
    }
    if (extendedCodeLevel == 0 && code == ATTENTION_LEVEL_CODE)
        {
            short attentionValue = (value[0] & 0xFF);
            printf("%d\n", attentionValue);
            fprintf(arq2,"%d\n",attentionValue);
        }
    if (extendedCodeLevel == 0 && code == MEDITATION_LEVEL_CODE)
        {
            short meditationValue = (value[0] & 0xFF);
            printf("%d\n", meditationValue);
            fprintf(arq3,"%d\n",meditationValue);
        }
    fclose(arq1);
    fclose(arq2);
    fclose(arq3);
}
private: System::Void IniciarCaptura_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    SerialPort* port = new SerialPortW32();

    if (port->open())
    {
        /* Initialize ThinkGear stream parser */
        ThinkGearStreamParser parser;
        THINKGEAR_initParser(&parser, PARSER_TYPE_PACKETS, handleDataValueFunc, NULL);

        unsigned char byteRead;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            if (port->read(&byteRead, 1) == 1)
            {
                THINKGEAR_parseByte(&parser, byteRead);
                fflush(stdout);
            }
            else
            {
                //cerr << "Erro na leitura da porta" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }

        port->close();
    }
    else
    {
        //cout << port->getErrorMessage() << endl;
    }
    delete port;
    //return 0;
    }
};
```

}

I've already tried to add a "&" before "handleDataValueFunc", but it only returns another error message. Can anybody help?

Comment: What is the other error message? What line do you get the error on?

Comment: This is a function definition. Where is it used. I assume you're passing it as a callback somewhere else.

Comment: Is `THINKGEAR_initParser` your code? Can you share its code?

Comment: The error specifically says "use '&MindSet::Form1::handleDataValueFunc'" and not "use '&handleDataValueFunc".

Comment: The error comes from the line
"THINKGEAR_initParser(&parser, PARSER_TYPE_PACKETS, handleDataValueFunc, NULL);"

If I use " &MindSet::Form1::handleDataValueFunc " I get the following error:


Error 4 error C3374: can't take address of 'MindSet::Form1::handleDataValueFunc' unless creating delegate instance c:\documents and settings\licap\desktop\mindset\mindset\mindset\Form1.h 122 1 MindSet

Comment: If you're in C++ .Net, then yes, you have to create a delegate. That's how I did it 10 years ago, at least.

Comment: I suppose that `handleDataValueFunc` is actually a member function, right? Is it possible that THINKGEAR_initParser takes a plain function pointer? You can't replace it with the member function pointer as it is not the same thing (actually member fn ptr is not really a pointer at all). Try to move `handleDataValueFunc` out of the class.

Comment: Instead of moving it out of class, just make it `static`. A pointer to a **static** member function is in fact compatible with plain function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `gcroot`  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f.aspx

```
struct nativeMindSetFormHandle
{
    nativeMindSetFormHandle(MindSet::Form1 ^ h) : handle(h) {}
    gcroot<MindSet::Form1 ^> handle;
};

static void handleDataValueFuncProxy(unsigned char extendedCodeLevel,
    unsigned char code, unsigned char valueLength, const unsigned char *value,
    void *customData)
{
    static_cast<nativeMindSetFormHandle *>(customData)->handle->handleDataValueFunc(extendedCodeLevel, code, valueLength, value, NULL);
}
```

And update `IniciarCaptura_Click` to include:

```
nativeMindSetFromHandle * nativeHandle = new nativeMindSetFormHandle(this);
THINKGEAR_initParser(&parser, PARSER_TYPE_PACKETS, handleDataValueFuncProxy, nativeHandle);
```

And don't forget to `delete nativeHandle` when you are done.